# Do a partition over using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to use `dplyr` in order to construct an observation count, much the same way in which SQL would use a `partition over` function. It must specifically be `dplyr` due to its speed when handling big data structures

Imagine we have a dataset as follows:

```
>Letters
A
A
A
B
B
A
B
C
C
D
A
C
```

And I want to get something as follows:

```
Letters Count
A   1
A   2
A   3
B   1
B   2
A   4
B   3
C   1
C   2
D   1
A   5
C   3
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `df1 %>% group_by(Letters) %>% mutate(Count = row_number())`

Comment: You are fast....was answering. :)

Comment: Or `ave(Letters,Letters,FUN=seq_along)`.

Comment: I can see how this question can be seen as a duplicate. But as this question specifically asks for a `dplyr` variation in the application (other answers use `data.table`), I will leave it for now.